# WordPress Enqueue necessary with Webpack bundling?

Tags: wordpress, webpack

Is it still necessary to enqueue my scripts/styles with the WP enqueue function if I bundle my assets and manage my dependencies beforehand with Webpack?

Seems much easier to just inject the hashed scripts/styles into `header.php` and `footer.php` via Webpack.

In the end I only have `main.css`, `main.js`, `vendor.js` and whatever chunk I load asynchronously (whos dependencies are also managed by Webpack).

Could someone give me a reason to use enqueue functions?

Comment: If you think you have a handle on webpack, then no, there's no advantage to enqueing anything else.

Comment: How you solve 3rd party plugins enqueue? Did you find any way to handle them via webpack?

Comment: You could copy the scripts from the plugin folder to your theme folder, I suppose. I don't have an automated solution yet.